# PyCharm: Django templates don't seem to be working?

Tags: django, pycharm

I am trying to use Django in PyCharm, but the Django templates are not working. For example {% block %} elements and {{variable}} references are not treated specially and when I view the page preview, it just displays it as text?

Comment: did you setup the template folder in settings.py?

Comment: i am not sure the problem comes from Pycharm, can you show code where you render a template and your settings.py  ?

Answer (score 1):

first go to pychram preferences :
[image]

select your project and chooce project structure and assign the values in the top to let pycharm what is you project structure:
[image]

from this page select Template languages:
[image]

select django
[image]